# How to transform rtabmap/odom?

Tags: slam, navigation, quaternion, rtabmap-odometry, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to compare the visual odometry from RTABMAP (Kinect 2) with ground truth. But it provides odometry rotated 90 degrees around. How to align it with ground truth?
Sorry for my English.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288261/how-to-transform-rtabmap/odom?/) by [vkpankov](https://answers.ros.org/users/34558/vkpankov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2018-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rtabmap follows [REP 103 Coordinate Frame Conventions](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html#coordinate-frame-conventions). If you try the [hand-held tutorial for Kinect v2](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/HandHeldMapping), you will see that an optical rotation is added with a [static_transform_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/tf#static_transform_publisher) between `camera_link` and `kinect2_link` frames:

```
 $ rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 -1.5707963267948966 0 -1.5707963267948966 camera_link kinect2_link 100
```

then launch [rgbd_odometry](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/#Visual_Odometry) with `_frame_id:=camera_link` so that odometry is computed in ROS coordinates and not image coordinates.

Is your ground truth also in ROS coordinates? If not, you may need to add a TF to be so.

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2018-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2